Will Android fix erase files on USB?
I was hacked and managed to transfer most of my laptop data to a USB device. USB has a mini USB port for a Type C like my Android phone. I have an unactivated Android phone that is showing the files, but it wants to fix the USB and I need those files.
Will fixing the USB destroy or erase the data stored?

Since you used your laptop to write to the USB, it is highly likely that it was not formatted suitably.  If it was Windows, it probably used NTFS.  Android will not work with NTFS, it will work with FAT32.
Do not let anything write to it in any way.  Take it to a friends place to look at it from a laptop, and make a copy of it first.
